# Windows 10: How can I delete Display 2/Restore factory display settings?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, display-settings

**BACKGROUND:**

- I have a new Dell laptop, Windows 10 Pro, with Intel Iris(R) Xe graphics.
- I tried to add a second display, an old Acer G185H monitor.
- When I plugged the Acer into the HDMI port, Windows 10 detected it ... but the monitor said "Input not supported".
- I tried different refresh rates (60Hz and 59.950Hz are the only options Advanced Display Settings gives me) and different resolutions (it originally defaulted to 1920x1080), to no avail.

**PROBLEM:**

- At some point, the Acer became my main display (whoops!)
- If I unplug the HDMI...everything works.  But I can't change any Display2 settings.
- If I plug in the HDMI... then I get two black screens.

  My laptop monitor is "black"...and my Acer monitor says "Input not supported".  There's no Windows desktop - I'm stuck.

Q: How do I get Windows to "forget" Display 2 (so I can try again)?

Q: Any suggestions what I can do about "input not supported" (once I get past "two black screens")?

---

**Update:**

I tried simply plugging in a different monitor ... but they're all DisplayPort only :(

So I ordered a DisplayPort => HDMI cable from Amazon.  Hopefully it'll arrive tomorrow...